# Boolean modifier cannot be executed error

Tags: materials, modifiers, text-object, bmesh

I'm trying to create a background for a friend with his username, so I've created two text objects, and given them meshes. I hope to make some pretty cool semi-transparent materials for them. However, some of the materials for the objects' perimeter shows through from under the front and back surfaces. I understand the Boolean modifier can perform a "negative extrusion" so to speak on the area in which the two objects intersect, but when I select carve, I get a warning saying that the modifier cannot be executed. Can anyone tell me how to correct this?

Comment: please add at least a screenshot of your setup (edit the question, add the image with the relevant editor button), so that we can understand it...

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34781/boolean-modifier-not-working/34787#34787 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50611/boolean-modifiers-not-working-normally/50632#50632

Comment: and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34451/how-to-cut-holes-in-an-object-using-another-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mesh is open, and that is when the Boolean modifier will start to complain. You have to close the mesh. When you mentioned that parts of the mesh are showing through, it proves that your mesh is open. To fix this, you should redo the whole process, perhaps with a less complex font to make sure weird things do not happen to your mesh (that is if you are using another font apart from the default). Hope this helped!

Comment: Okay. I managed to figure it out. Thanks man.