# Partial shape subtracting using the Boolean modifier

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I want to subtract the upper cylinder from object below.
[image]

Using the Boolean modifier in difference-mode, the complete object disappears.

[image]
Here is the [Blender-File](https://linx.li/selif/sticksaeger-ventilatorv3.blend)

PS. I am new and almost always objects react weird when i am following a tutorial (like Array around an object).

Comment: A comprehensive post on booleans can be found here: [Boolean Modifier not working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34781/boolean-modifier-not-working)

Comment: Remove Boolean modifier from the wheel. Select the vertical cylinder and add Boolean to this object, in the Boolean Modifier window select "Object: InnererK", then "Operation: Intersect". This will do what you want I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to fix/flip/recalculate your normals on the top cylinder. To fix it...

Select it

<kbd>Tab</kbd> into edit mode.

<kbd>T</kbd> to toggle the tool panel @ left.

Click the Shading/UV tab.

Click `Flip Direction`

<kbd>Tab</kbd> to toggle back to Object mode.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> >> Rotation & Scale.

Try your boolean operation again, make sure the difference option is set.

Comment: I don't know what that is doing (I will look into it), but it works. Thank you.

Comment: When I answered this, I was really trying to find an answer on blender.stackexchange.com that I remembered seeing a while back ago that fit your case, but for the life of me I couldn't; but then I found the post [Here it is](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50611/boolean-modifiers-not-working-normally?rq=1). It should explain your issue fairly clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try another couple of things if flipping the normals doesn't get it done. I find that nine out of ten times a boolean doesn't work because of scale rotation issues. cntrl>A on each object in the scene individually to make sure that the rotation and scale are all the same. I also find the bool tools addon absolutely brilliant.