# Boolean Modifer Not Working Properly

Tags: modifiers

When I Try To Use The Boolean Modifier To Carve The White Object Into The Other One Via Difference, It Just Makes The Grey One Disappear.[image: Why is 3d Modeling So Hard, oh yeah computers]

Also This Does Not Occur When I Use The B-Mesh Solver, only The Carve Solver

Comment: Have you tried to recalculate the normals on the grey model?

Comment: You might want to check [this out](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50611/boolean-modifiers-not-working-normally?rq=1)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured Out I Need To Combine It With A Larger Object, Apply The Boolean, Separate The Objects, Then It Works.