# Difference Boolean Acting as if it is a Union

Tags: modeling, modifiers

So. I've been working on modeling an M4A1, but I'm currently working on the handguard (which is a 9 inch RIS) and has holes running in between the rails. I'm using a boolean to make these cuts, and it is acting as though it is a mix of union and a difference. Before posting I have: checked and edited normals, checked for non manifold (there is none), moved stuff around, added some support loops for better connection points, and separating each individual cutter. To no avail. Any help would be appreciated[image: Object mode view][image: Edit mode view]

Comment: Could you point out which object is supposed to cut out which?

Comment: Are those marked-sharp edges split? _Maybe_ get rid of those and use Auto-Smooth instead?

Comment: The normals of the object determine how the boolean will work. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50611/boolean-modifiers-not-working-normally?noredirect=1&lq=1 Read also this extensive post on boolans: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34787/92768

Comment: Check the boolean modifier for the new exact option and try toggling it to fast.

Comment: and a provided .blend file always helps best, because then we don't have to guess what is going on or wrong ;)

Comment: i fixed this issue a while ago. The issue was the bool objects were overlapping. not sure why that would have an effect but it did